# Copiar solo datos diferentes entre dos tablas que tienen la misma estructura

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Debido a actualizaciones que hicimos en sistemas, tuvimos que corregir algunos errores en nuestra DB. La base de datos vieja se llama "suitecrm", la nueva "suitecrm_new".
Ambas bases tienen las mismas tablas con las mismas estructuras.
El problema es que, por ejemplo, algunas tablas de la nueva DB no tienen exactamente los mismos registros que la tabla de la antigua DB.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, lo que necesito es una Query que me permita copiar de la tabla de la antigua DB a la misma tabla de la nueva DB solo aquellos campos en los que haya información distinta. Aclaro que tengo identificado el ID de los registros que son diferentes.

Comment: Y... Qué has intentado? Suena quieres que resolvamos tu problema. Cuál es **exactamente** tu pregunta? El título de la pregunta suena más a un requerimiento. Qué **exactamente** estás preguntando?

Comment: Si ya tienes identificados los ID usa una sentencia de tipo `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... WHERE ID IN ()`  o simplemente con un `LEFT JOIN`. Te recomiendo [hacer el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas cómo funciona la comunidad.

Comment: ¿Quieres insertar algunas filas y actualizar otras? ¿Quieres que, al final, toda la tabla en la nueva base de datos sea exactamente igual a la tabla en la base de datos anterior?

Answer (score 0):

Si logro entender lo que dices, es que deseas poblar los registros de la base de datos nuevas con los registros de la base antigua?, pero solo los registros que no estan en la nueva, y suponiendo que los ID no se cruzan de las tablas de la base nueva con la base antigua seria algo asi:

```
insert into suitecrm_new.dbo.tabla
select *
  from suitecrm.dbo.tabla x
 where not exists (select 1 from suitecrm_new.dbo.tabla where id = x.id)
```